# QDataStream custom writing - one vs multiple lines;

Tags: c++, qt, operator-overloading, qdatastream

I'll write a custom operator for my `struct`, and I'm wondering if there is any difference in performance between the two:

```
QDataStream &operator<<(QDataStream &out, const Event &event)
{
    out << event.a;
    out << event.b;
    out << event.c;
}

QDataStream &operator<<(QDataStream &out, const Event &event)
{
    out << event.a
        << event.b
        << event.c;
}
```

Comment: Even if there were, it would probably be negligible

Comment: No. Use what makes your code clearer and easier to understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`QDataStream` `operator<<` overloads [return a reference](https://github.com/RSATom/Qt/blob/af80d7ef4343b96603dad8287920b26e03fdf557/qtbase/src/corelib/io/qdatastream.cpp#L894) to the `QDataStream` object so there's no appreciable performance difference between the two (your snippets would likely result in the same generated code).

Use whichever you feel makes your code more readable.